# how to show database changes in web pages(whiteout reloading page)?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

i am working on simple hotel reservation system that users enter their info, like hotel or room. in every page i have footer bar that show feedback of system when user do something. for example when user add hotel , after doing this,when he redirect to any pages, in footer bar, immediately, display , "hotel added successfully".

```
|----------------------------------------|
|                                        | 
|               GridView                 | 
|                                        | 
|                                        |
|----------------------------------------|
|hotel added successfully !              |
|----------------------------------------|
```

the solution that i am using is :
when users log something , i log it
and i define div[id=notification] in shared/_layout, and using a worker to call a function that check log database and get new ones.

```
// i use worker to repeatedly invoke function to check db
    var worker = new Worker('../Scripts/worker.js');
    worker.addEventListener('message', function (e) 
    {
      if (e.data != "")
      {
         var result = e.data;
         var results = result.split("##");                
         if ($("#notificationID").val() != results[1])
         {                    
            $("#notificationID").val(results[1]);       
         }            
      }
    }, false);
```

and the function to check db is

```
public string GetNewTrans()
{            
   string userName = Membership.GetUser().UserName;
   using (var context = new jobEntities())
   {
    var query = from p in context.Logs where p.UserName==userName && p.IsNew == null orderby p.ID_Log descending select p;
       if (query.Count() > 0)
       {
          var log = query.FirstOrDefault();                        
          DateTime c= DateTime.Parse(log.RefreshDate.ToString());
          var sec = DateTime.Now.Subtract(c).Seconds;
          if( sec> 2)
          {
             log.IsNew = "false";
             context.SaveChanges();
          }
          var result = log.Section + " : " + log.Action +"@@"+log.Success.ToString()+"##"+log.ID_Log.ToString();
                        return result;
        }
        return null;
      }                      
 }
```

now i think that when number of users increase , the load of check db increase and cause to make pages slower.
so do you have any better solution ?
and my framework in asp mvc 3.5 and use EF 4.1

Answer (score 0):

The better solution to get some data from db its using JsonResult action controller to get json data and than modified on the client.

As for info messages you can add TempData["message"] object in your controller and in  redirecting View

Comment: JsonResult is good idea, i forget about it, thanks.but because i dont want to use reload page then using redirect and is not possible